# Select postgresql for combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql, combinations, postgresql-9.3

I have the following 2 tables:
[SQL Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTDuc.png)

I have a list of ids (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ..., 10000).
Unique combination of those ids is inserted into another table.

So, how can I find these inique combination If I pass the list of ids to search.

E.g., I search for `ARRAY([2,3,4])`. The combination exisst only for the unique_combnation 1, so the result will be as follows:

```
1 3
1 2
1 4
```

There is no any unique_comb which contains ids ARRAY([2,3,4]).

If I search for [1,4], the results will be as follows:

```
1 3
1 2
1 4
2 2
2 4
2 5
```

How can I do it? I know how to do it in a bad way:

1. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1
2. Iterate over given ids: `SELECT * FROM .. where id = ANY(ARRAY[1,4])` and get all rows, insert into t1 all rows.
3. Then group everything by unique_comb.
4. Then count the number of groups. If the number of unique combinations is not more than 1, then return the id of the unique combination, else (unique combinations > 1) return nothing

Is it a way to make it with 1-2 sql lines? I am using postgresql 9.3

```
select unique_comb t2 where id = ANY(ARRAY[1, 4]) group by unique_comb ...
```

The answer below is correct. I have modifed just a little bit the query and it began to work.

It will choose several ids from table unique thing.

The result will be of `select unique_comb, array_agg(id) t2 where id = ANY(ARRAY[1, 4]) group by unique_comb` will be as follows:

Comment: Your second example does not seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that you describe is seems to be something like a `group by`:

```
select unique_comb
from t2
where id = ANY(ARRAY[1, 4])
group by unique_comb
having count(*) = array_length(ARRAY[1, 4], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***big*** tables, and ***long*** arrays (not for your examples with just 2 or 3 elements), a more sophisticated query with a recursive CTE would be faster.

In any case you need an index on `(id, unique_comb)` - in this order! A primary key serves nicely.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT unique_comb, id, 2 AS i  -- start with index for 2nd array elem
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id = 5  -- *first* element array

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.unique_comb, t.id, c.i + 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   tbl t USING (unique_comb)
   WHERE  t.id = ('{5, ... long array ... , 4}'::int[])[c.i]  -- your array here
   )
SELECT unique_comb
FROM   cte
WHERE  id = 4;  -- *last* element of array
```

The advantage of this approach is to rule out most (or all) rows early in the game. If you have information on value frequencies, you would put the rarest elements first.